# AMD's R7 360X or Nvidia's GTX 750ti?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, ati

I'm building a new computer on which I want to use Linux (probably Ubuntu) as it's OS. I already picked all the hardware except the GPU. I can't chose between Nvidia or AMD.
Link to my build on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/ref=nav_wishlist_btn

My CPU is AMD's FX 8320 (3,5 GHZ, 8 core) so at first I picked R7 360X for my GPU but then I took a look at some forums and find a benchmark which was made about a year ago. Here is the link:http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amdnv-phoronix-11&num=1

From the benchmarks I could clearly see that Nvidia wins over AMD. I also know that AMD has never had a good drivers support on Linux and was always lacking behind, but I know that they had improved a lot in past few years.  I also know that there is nothing wrong to have an AMD's CPU together with Nvidia's GPU and that you won't have any decrease in performance. Please correct me if I'm mistaking. The question I want to ask you is the following.

Which one should I pick then? AMD's **R7 360X** or Nvidia's **GTX 750ti**?

Comment: You should ask this question in forums like this(http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/forum-33.html). Regarding ubuntu - it has the drivers for both and will be working fine. I have 2 systems with nvidia graphics card and there is no issue in Ubuntu for them.

Comment: Definitely Nvidia. I had troubles with AMD driver, it was worse than default one.

Comment: Sry, didn't know that I'm not alowed to ask things like this in here...:( But the ask Ubuntu comunity is sooo damn fast so I couldn't resist it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if this is opinion based, I definitely recommend to choose the NVIDIA GPU. Not only because of the performance benchmarks, most important of all is the drivers support for the operating system. Ubuntu always ships with the latest stable drivers from the NVIDIA long-lived branch. Additionally the latest official drivers are available from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA. Generally the NVIDIA drivers support is way better than the drivers support  from AMD.
The installation process works easy and smooth, when everything is done correctly.